# Proving entire function constant

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

$f$ is entire and $f(z)=f(z+1)=f(z+i)$

prove $f(z)=const$

I have no clue how to solve it

Comment: What do you know about a bounded entire function?

Comment: @user122036: Can you see why it is a bounded function?

Comment: @Manasi I actually dont

Comment: Have a look at Liouville's Theorem. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville's_theorem_(complex_analysis)

Comment: Im sorry, I meant to tag Manasi... Of course I know liouvilles

Comment: @ user122036 : Now f(z+2) = f(z+1) = f(z). So, what is f(z+ n)? Similarly, what is f(z + in)? In both cases n is a natural number.

Comment: No, look at your question. That will help.

Comment: f(z+n)=f(z)
f(z+in)=f(z)

Comment: You have a function that is "periodic". If this were a periodic function on $\mathbf{R}$ instead of $\mathbf{C}$, how would you prove that it was bounded?

Comment: Yes, thats right. From here, can you work out that for any complex number w, f(w) will lie in a bounded region? Hint :$ f(in)= f(n) = f(0)$.

Comment: if it was in R so periodic function is bounded,but in C it's not

Comment: Why not? Anyway, check that any complex number $w= x + iy$ can be written as $ w = r + [x] + it + i[y]$ where $ r= x - [x]$ and $t = y - [y]$. Can you take it on from here? This is pretty easy.

Comment: @Manasi I agree, this problem should be trivial if you know Liouville's theorem and have been told to apply it....

Comment: @Swanson : Yes, I think the OP needs to figure out how the function is bounded  to later apply Liouville's theorem.

Comment: If it was $\mathbf{R}$, you would show the function was bounded over one period. How would you do that?

Comment: Let $f(a+1)=f(a)$, for $a∈R.$(Here 1 is the period). Now for any real number $t$, we would have that $f(t)$ would lie between $f(0)$ and $f(1)$. Can you see this? Please try.

Answer (score 3):

The key point in showing boundedness is that $|f|$ is continuous (since $f$ is entire) on  a "period" or unit square in the complex plane: $\{x+iy; 0\le x,y \le 1\}$ which is compact (analogous in this case to a closed interval in $\mathbb{R}$), so $|f|$ attains its maximum $M$ on this square. Then every adjacent square has an identical image, and since $\mathbb{C}$  is equal to the union of these squares, for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$, $f(z) = f(x+iy)$ for some $x,y\in[0,1]$.

For example, in case it is not clear enough, the unit square to the right: $\{x+iy; 1\le x\le 2, 0\le y \le 1 \}$. We have $f(x+iy) = f((x-1)+iy+1) = f((x-1)+iy)$ where the argument $(x-1)+iy$ belongs to the original unit square, and so $|f(x+iy)|\le M$.

From there you do as others said and apply Louisville's.

Answer (score 1):

As many of the comments suggest, your function $ f $ is bounded.

Look up "doubly periodic functions."

The reason for the bounded comes from the fact that $ f $ can be thought of as a function from a compact set. The continuity of $ f $ makes the image compact, which is closed and bounded (as far as Euclidean spaces go).